# Looping through everysingle text column in a database and doing a replace

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to loop through every single `varchar`, `nvarchar` and `ntext` column in a database and running a `replace` statement on it using the `@string`.

However, when the field has only a max length of 50, it should run the replace statement using the `@shortstring` only.  Like the code below sort of...

What I have so far is something like this:

```
Declare @string varchar(100), @shortstring varchar(50)
Set @string = 'fullstring_100_characters'
Set @shortstring = 'shortstring_50_characters'

Update [Table] Set [Column] = Replace([Column],@string,'')
```

But if it's an `ntext` the statement looks like this, and always uses the `@string` instead of the `@shortstring`

```
Update [Table] Set [Column] = CAST(REPLACE(CAST([Column] as NVarchar(MAX)),@string,'') AS NText)
```

Can someone show me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to update text or ntext fields you will have to use `UPDATETEXT`. Refer the link below for the detail info:

[Update text/ntext or varchar(max) data-type columns in SQL Server](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/update-textntext-or-varcharmax-data-type-columns-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

First I have to ask you to replace your ntext fields with nvarchar(max), ntext is trouble

quote from microsoft

"ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Fixed and variable-length data types for storing large non-Unicode and Unicode string and binary data. Unicode data uses the UNICODE UCS-2 character set. " quote end

This is how to change the datatypes:

```
alter table yourtable ALTER COLUMN colname varchar(max)
```

Here is a script to replace the texts as you described in all tables and columns. the script will whine a bit if there is a computed column in a TABLE, but it will still execute:

```
DECLARE @searchvalue varchar(100)
DECLARE @newvalue varchar(100)
DECLARE @newvalueShort varchar(50)
SET nocount off

SET @searchvalue = 'replace text'
SET @newvalue = 'new long text replacement'
SET @newvalueShort = 'short text'

SELECT * into #t FROM 
(
SELECT 'update [' + a.TABLE_name + '] 
SET ['+ column_name+ ']=replace(' +column_name +','''+@searchvalue +''','''+ case when character_maximum_length > 50 then @newvalue else @newvalueShort end + ''')
where [' +a.column_name+
'] like ''%'+@searchvalue +'%''' sqlstring
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
join 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES b
ON a.TABLE_name = b.TABLE_name
and b.TABLE_type = 'base TABLE'
WHERE data_type in ('varchar', 'char', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
and character_maximum_length >= len(@newvalueShort)
) a

DECLARE @sqlstring as nvarchar(500)
DECLARE SqlCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT sqlstring FROM #t
OPEN SqlCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
INTO @sqlstring
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     EXEC(@sqlstring)
     FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
     INTO @sqlstring
END
CLOSE SqlCursor
DEALLOCATE SqlCursor
DROP TABLE #t
```